# Изменение значения поля SQL запросом

Tags: sql, modx

Нужно убрать пробелы в значении дополнительного поля с id = 9

В таблице **modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues** выполняю SQL запрос:

```
UPDATE  `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`
SET  `value` = REPLACE(  ' ',  '',  `value` )
WHERE `tmplvarid` = 9
```

В результате значение поля **value** у строк становятся пустыми. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о [функции REPLACE() в MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), то вы перепутали порядок аргументов - строка или имя столбца надо указывать в качестве *первого* аргумента:

```
UPDATE  `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`
SET  `value` = REPLACE(`value`,  ' ',  '')
WHERE `tmplvarid` = 9
```